# Intuitive explanation of the fact that fundamental group of the base space can be indentified as set with fiber?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be simply connected topological space and $p:(X,x) \to (B,b)$ be a Covering map.

> Is there any intuitive explanation of the fact that $\pi_1(B,b)$ is isomorphic to $p^{-1}(b)$ as a set?

I know the proof of the result but i am interested in 'intuitive' explanation.

P.S: I have just started to learn about Covering spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, your best way of understanding this is via the correspondence through path lifting.

A loop $\gamma$ in $(B,b)$ lifts uniquely to a path $\tilde{\gamma}$ in $(X,x)$ such that $\tilde{\gamma}(0)=x$ and $\tilde{\gamma}(1)$ is a point in $p^{-1}(b)$. Therefore we have a map $\pi_1(B,b) \to p^{-1}(b)$ given by $\gamma \mapsto \tilde{\gamma}(1)$.

Of course, to turn this into a proof, one needs to show that this map is well defined up to homotopy of loops, that it is surjective when $\pi_1(X,x)=0$ and that it is injective.

Whenever I think about this correspondence, I personally imagine the example of the covering map $(\mathbb{R},0) \to (S^1,1)$ given by $x\mapsto \exp(2\pi ix)$ and then picture how a loop going round the circle once gets lifted up to $\mathbb{R}$, then a loop going round the circle twice, then going around once in the other direction (corresponding to $-1\in\pi_1(S^1,1)$), etc.